# ReactJS dashboard using dc.JS and nivo charts

Tags: reactjs, dc.js, crossfilter, nivo-react

I was working on a reactJS dashboard PoC, with data filtering/slicing capability across charts.

Zeroed on dcjs and nivo charts for their capabilities.

I would like to understand whether nivo charts can be used in conjunction with dc.js.

As nivo charts are build on top of d3.js, thought it should be straight forward.

It looks like the registration of nivo charts with dc.js is not possible.

Any leads or reference material on this is really appreciated

Thanks

SD

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: D3 is very low level and I would argue it doesn’t even know what a “chart” is. Any web chart can be integrated with dc.js but it’s not trivial. I’ve worked up simple examples but not the full filtering demo yet (and that will always require significant writing of code and refactoring).

Comment: I haven’t seen nivo charts before - do they have brushing / selection? That would be a prerequisite.